# MongoDB w Authentication & Roles : how to manage DB access in REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to MongoDB, and I wonder how to use the authentication + authorisation features ..
I read (and quite understood) the MongoDB doc about setting the roles and privileges for admin and users.

However I cannot relate it with the API coding I could read in all tuts

1- there is only one DB connection with one username/password

```
db: 'mongodb://apiuser:apiPassword@localhost:7272/api-staging-db'
```

2- in the login route a check is perform against a User collection which is not the system.users collection

Is there any tuts or examples in which I can discover how to handle the authentication/authorization with the  system roles & privileges ? or any guidelines ...

thanks for your feedback

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood the question correctly. But i think you are confusing the database authentication with your application authentication.

Comment: yes,  that's my point... you understood very well !  Shortly can I use the database authentication system to authenticate and authorize client users to perform actions according to user's roles and privileges...
In Ruby On Rails I have to use a plugin like CanCan to manage such privileges not the DB security system...   is it the same w Express/MongoDB  or is there a way to use the MongoDB auth system ?

Comment: I don't believe that MongoDB has such feature built-in. But if it does why would you want to hit the database each time you want to verify if some user is autorised? Anyway  i've found this library, similar to cancan you mentioned but for javascript: https://github.com/vadimdemedes/cancan

Comment: thanks a lot ... you put me on tracks...  I also found node-acl, thanks for the cancan lib... will test both...